# Checkbox state change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

In the below code initially  checkbox unchecked and textboxes disabled.when i click checkbox then textboxes enabled BUT after the enabled when i again unchecked checkboxes it need to be disabled.But that partis not working(else part)
Code

```
 $(function(){
    $("#txtres").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#txtres2").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $("#chknew").click(function () {
        if("#chknew").is(:checked)
        {
        $("#txtres").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#txtres2").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
      else
      {
         $("#txtres").attr("disabled", "disabled");
         $("#txtres2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: ohhhh I see, aren't you getting an error your if has a missing `)` in last.

Comment: `.is(:checked)` => `.is(':checked')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with "change" handler

```
$(function(){
   $("#txtres").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   $("#txtres2").attr("disabled", "disabled");

$('#chknew').change(function () {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $("#txtres").removeAttr("disabled");
       $("#txtres2").removeAttr("disabled");
   } else {
       $("#txtres").attr("disabled", "disabled");
       $("#txtres2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it again disabled, Say like bellow

```
$("#txtres").prop("disabled", true);
```

instead of

```
$("#txtres").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: You should use `.prop()` instead. `.attr()` is not suitable for boolean attributes like disabled, readonly and the likes.

Comment: @Terry updated my answer. Reading about how it helps.

Comment: In my code disabled partis working,Butin the else part coding not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#txtres").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#txtres2").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    $("#chknew").click(function () {    
        $("#txtres").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
        $("#txtres2").attr("disabled", !this.checked);          
    });
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/w2jtg1b9/3/

Comment: When i checked it i wantedto enabled the TextBoxes